# How to determine device name attached with my PC?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two devices (Genovation Keypad and FUJITSU palm scanner) attached with my PC. If I take input from any of them then how to determine which device gave me input?

I have use this piece of code to confirm that device is attached with the PC.

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management; // need to add System.Management to your project references.

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var usbDevices = GetUSBDevices();

        string text = "";
        foreach (var usbDevice in usbDevices)
        {
            text += string.Format("Device ID: {0}, PNP Device ID: {1}, Description: {2}",
                usbDevice.DeviceID, usbDevice.PnpDeviceID, usbDevice.Description) + Environment.NewLine;
        }

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"d:\Rough\AllConnectedDevices.txt", text);

    }

    static List<USBDeviceInfo> GetUSBDevices()
    {
        List<USBDeviceInfo> devices = new List<USBDeviceInfo>();

        ManagementObjectCollection collection;

        using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity"))
            collection = searcher.Get();

        foreach (var device in collection)
        {
            devices.Add(new USBDeviceInfo(
            (string)device.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID"),
            (string)device.GetPropertyValue("PNPDeviceID"),
            (string)device.GetPropertyValue("Description")
            ));
        }

        collection.Dispose();
        return devices;
    }
}

class USBDeviceInfo
{
    public USBDeviceInfo(string deviceID, string pnpDeviceID, string description)
    {
        this.DeviceID = deviceID;
        this.PnpDeviceID = pnpDeviceID;
        this.Description = description;
    }
    public string DeviceID { get; private set; }
    public string PnpDeviceID { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }
}
```

Output:
Device ID: HID\VID_04B4&PID_0100\6&1474E62E&1&0000, PNP Device ID: HID\VID_04B4&PID_0100\6&1474E62E&1&0000, Description: HID Keyboard Device

Device ID: USB\VID_04C5&PID_1084\5&36C74247&0&3, PNP Device ID: USB\VID_04C5&PID_1084\5&36C74247&0&3, Description: FUJITSU PalmSecure Sensor Device

Comment: you have description then whats problem ?

Comment: Yes, description is there but when I press number 1 from keypad I get 1 on  Window_TextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e) event      e.g. e.Text = 1